# Add control at runtime to user control's inner panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control that contains 2 panels. Panel1 is the parent for Panel2 so Panel2 is placed inside the Panel1 container. Now, at runtime, I want to add controls to my user control. These new controls must be placed inside Panel2. Addings controls with `myUserControl.Controls.Add` would normally put the new controls into the user control itself and not inside Panel2. I would like Panel2 to be the default container for all controls that are added to the user control at runtime. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [OnControlAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.oncontroladded), verify whether the UC Handle is already created (`InitiaizeComponent()` has already being executed, so all child Controls added in the Designer have already been added to the UC's Controls collection), then add the new Control to `Panel2.Controls` collection:

```
Public Class MyUSerControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Protected Overrides Sub OnControlAdded(e As ControlEventArgs)
        If IsHandleCreated AndAlso e.Control IsNot Panel1 Then
            Panel2.Controls.Add(e.Control)
        End If
        MyBase.OnControlAdded(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or, you could add a public method that performs this action:

```
Dim btn1 = New Button() With {.Text = "Button1", .Name = "Button1"}
Dim btn2 = New Button() With {.Text = "Button2", .Name = "Button2"}

myUSerControl.AddControls(btn1)
' Or
myUSerControl.AddControls({btn1, btn2})
```

---

```
Public Class MyUSerControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Sub AddControls(ParamArray newControls As Control())
        Panel2.Controls.AddRange(newControls)
    End Sub
End Class
```